# Created DAX table based on two columns from two different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have these two tables in PowerBI:

Table 1

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | el1 | el1 |
| 2 | el2 | el2 |

Table 2

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | el1 | el1 |
| y | el2 | el2 |

And i want to have the following table:

Table 3

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | y |

How can i do this in DAX or PowerQuery?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to produce all the combinations of the first column from both tables?

In Table1 in powerquery, click select first column, right click, remove other columns. Then add column, custom column with formula

```
=Table2[C1]
```

Use arrows atop the column to expand to new rows

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"C1"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", each Table2[C1]),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom")
in  #"Expanded Custom"
```

If you are trying to do some matching, it is not obvious

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple DAX; but column_names(C1)should be different.

```
Table3 =
CROSSJOIN ( VALUES ( 'Table1'[C1] ), VALUES ( 'Table2'[C1**] ) )
```